# Set of true statements generated by set of axioms with a binary operator

Tags: logic, axioms

I wondered about this and I am having a hard time formulating it as a question at all, but I hope I can express something if my wondering here.

Assume we have a set $V = \{\mathbb N, +, =, X ,(,)\}$. Here $\mathbb N$ is the set of all natural numbers. The set $V$ contains our alphabet.

We also have set $A = \{ "1=1", "1+1=1+1", \dots, "1+1=2","1+1+1=3", \dots \}$. Set $A$ contains all the axioms. These are actually more like definitions, I believe, but they are axioms too.

Then let the set $T$ contains as elements all true statements. We know $A \subset T.$

Finally define binary operator $X$ as a function from $T^2 \to T$ such that if $a,b \in T, \ aXb \in T$, where $b$ is "applied" is some way (which seems rather difficult to define) to $a$.

A statement $s$ made using the elements of $V$ is in $T$ if $s = a_1Xa_2Xa_3...$ for some set of axioms, ie. $\forall i, a_i \in A$.

Assume we want to know if "theorem" $2+2 = 4$ is an element of $T$. Let's first name some axioms for simplicity: $$"1+1+1+1=1+1+1+1" = a_1 \\ "2 = 1+1" = a_2 \\ "4 = 1+1+1+1" = a_3$$

We can see, assuming a liberal definition of $X$: $$"1+1+1+1=1+1+1+1" X "2 = 1+1" = "2+1+1=1+1+1+1"$$ $$"2+1+1=1+1+1+1" X "2 = 1+1" = "2+2=1+1+1+1"$$ $$"2+2=1+1+1+1" X "4 = 1+1+1+1" = "2+2=4".$$ Thus $$"2+2 = 4" = (((a_1Xa_2)Xa_2)Xa_3).$$ Thus 2+2=4 is a true statement and thus an element of $T$.

Some questions: Does this make sense? Can such a binary operator on axioms be defined?  Could it be applied to "real" sets of axioms? Could the set of true statements form a group under such operator?

Comment: As an example, one axiom for actual addition would be the associative property (which is valid for even complex numbers): $\forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{C}: (a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$.  It seems to me that the way you say it, you want $A$ to consist of _all_ possible instances of this, i.g. $(1 + 1) + 1 = 1 + (1 + 1)$, $(1 + 1) + 2 = 1 + (1 + 2)$, etc..  In this case wouldn't $A \equiv T$?

Comment: @Jared I essentially selected this set of "axioms" only because it came first to mind and using the operator X seemed easy to use. I am not saying I want all instances you mentioned as axioms or even that there would exists infinitely many axioms. Essentially I am asking if there is a way to define a binary operator between true statements which would always return a true statement.

Comment: Again, using addition...Defining addition essentially defines the natural numbers.  For each natural number $n_i$ there is a unique natural number $n_{i + 1}$ such that $n_{i + 1} = n_i + 1$.  With associative and commutative axioms, we can verify every computation $n_i + n_j = n_k$ (by breaking the problem into $+\ 1$'s).  But that's a first order formula, the set it defines is the natural numbers (by applying this $+\ 1$ operator successively).